# How to convert a number with decimal values to a float in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

The issue is that I need to insert this number into json, and because the number contains a comma, json becomes invalid. A float would work because it contains a period not a comma.

I have tried using `replace(v_decimalNumber,',','.')` and it kind of works, except that the json property is converted to a string. I need it to remain some type of a numerical value.

How can this be achieved?

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: What is the datatype of `v_decimalNumber`? Numeric values in Oracle don't contain `,` or `.` or any other punctuation - those characters are just part of the formatting applied by `to_char` conversion or the displaying client.

Answer (score 0):

You just need `to_number()` function.

```
select to_number(replace('1,2', ',', '.')) float_nr from dual;
```

Result:

```
FLOAT_NR
1.2
```

Note that if your number has `.0` like `1.0`, the function will remove it and leave it only `1`

Comment: How do you get that? I have tried this before and tried it now, I only get `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error`

Comment: @Smk Please provide the number you are trying to convert.

Answer (score 0):

The data type of v_decimalNumber is some type of character format as it can contain commas (,). Your contention is that it contains a number once the commas are removed. However there is NO SUCH THING until that contention has been validated since being character I can put any character(s) I want into it subject to any length restriction. As an example a spreadsheet column that should contain numeric data. However, it that doesn't apply users will often put N/A into telling themselves that it doesn't apply. Oracle will happily load this into your v_decimalNumber. (And that's 1 of many many ways non-numeric data can get into your column.) So before attempting to process as a numeric value you must validate it is in fact valid numeric data. The following demonstrates one such way.

```
with some_numbers (n) as
     ( select '123,4456,789.00' from dual union all 
       select '987654321.00'    from dual union all 
       select '1928374655'      from dual union all
       select '1.2'             from dual union all
       select '.1'              from dual union all  
       select '1..1'            from dual union all 
       select 'N/A'             from dual
     )
   , rx as (select '^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$' regexp from dual) 
select n
     , case when regexp_like(replace(n,',',null), regexp)
            then to_number(replace(n,',',null))
            else null
       end Num_value
    , case when regexp_like(replace(n,',',null), regexp)
            then null
            else 'Not valid number'
      end msg
 from some_numbers,rx ;
```

Take away: Never trust a character type column to contain specific data requirements except random characters. Always validate then put the data into the appropriately defined columns.